# You cannot change `company[tax_id]` via API if an account is verified. Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

We have created a connect account using the API in Stripe. We followed the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create). The custom connected account can either be a "company" or an "individual" or "non-profit". We would also like to enable the user to change the tax_id (EIN) programatically. We use the following code

```
        custom_account_rep          = stripe.Account.modify(
            stripe_custom_account_id, 
            company = {'tax_id'    : center_ein} )
```

The following error is displayed.

```
 stripe error : InvalidRequestError(message='You cannot change `company[tax_id]` via API if an account is verified.
```

It is clear that we cannot enable the user to modify the account once it is verified. How do we get the "status" that the account is "verified"?

The account [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object) does not have any field called "status". Not sure if this is relevant, but we also have an external bank account linked to this custom connect account. The external bank account has a status (and its value is "new"). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there isn't just one field that you can check for the status of company verification for a Custom Connect account. For your specific use case, you can check a few fields on the Account object to see whether `company.tax_id` has been verified or not.

- Check `requirements.currently_due` and `requirements.past_due`. If `company.tax_id` is in either of these arrays, that means the tax ID needs to be set for the Account (because it was either never provided, or was provided and failed verification).
- Check `requirements.pending_verification`. If `company.tax_id` is in this array, that means it is currently going through verification and can still be updated.

You can read more about business verification here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#determining-if-identity-or-business-verification-is-needed

Comment: If requirements.currently_due and requirements.past_due return as empty arrays can we confirm that the status of the account is "verified". And can we confirm that if there is any entry in either of requirements.currently_due or requirements.past_due then we can allow the user to change the tax_id and account_type (company, individual, non-profits)?

Comment: Just to slightly clarify - if requirements.currently_due, requirements.past_due, AND requirements.pending_verification is empty then account is "verified". If there are any entries in requirements.currently_due or requirements.past_due then you can update the tax_id and business type